# Matrix Representation of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

I had one doubt in matrix form of linear equations

Say , we have a system of equations $Ax = b$ such that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $b$ is a $n\times 1$ matrix and so is $x$ then, if we are told that $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n$, then, do we need to check that $\operatorname{rank}(A|b)=n$ or can we say that since $b$ is a linear combination of the component vectors in $A$ then augmenting it in $A$ won't increase the number of linearly independent column vectors and hence the $\operatorname{rank}(A|b)=n$ and can't ever be $n+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand you when you write “do we need to check”. Assuming that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$, then $\operatorname{rank}(A|b)=n$ if and only if the system $Ax=b$ has a solution. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Oh okay sir. And if Ax = b had infinitely many solutions then can we say the same thing ? Thank you sir it helped clear things a little

Comment: @user435390 Well, yes, of course. If the system as infinitely many solutions, then, in particular, it has a solution.

Comment: Oh that was intuitive thank you :)

Comment: @user435390 If I was helpful, perhaps that you could mark my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Yes sir I just did that. Thanks :)